# What tactics can I use for China Infantry and GLA Demolition generals?

Tags: command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I play *Command and Conquer: Generals: Zero Hour* a lot with friends of mine, and none of us ever pick China Infantry or GLA Demolition generals. They just seem relatively useless compared to the other generals.

Is the game unbalanced, or are the strategies needed for these generals just not matching any of our play styles? If so, how are you supposed to play those generals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you hinted at you really do need to use the right strategy/play style for these generals. If you mainly play the US or China Tank Generals you will initially find it hard to use these Generals.

With both of these Generals the key is to flood the battlefield with cheap units. You need to get as many units as you can to overcome better defended enemy forces. Make sure your units are as spread-out as possible. This makes them less vulnerable to weapons with splash-damage (area-of-effect weapons) which are the biggest threat to these Generals.

Specifically for each General:

The Chinese Inf needs to use larger numbers of it's units to overpower stronger opponents.

The GLA Demolition General hinges on having a good constant flow of demo units to keep pounding away. More like a steady stream of units than a flood.

Answer (score 1):

GLA Demolition:
Choose your tactic according to your opponent. If USA go for a sucide bomber rush. I suggest a tunnel network than a barrack near their base. Create 2 RPG's and go for their supply heli. Even if they loose 1 heli its a loss of damn big money. Make sure to take out their barracks first.
When China make your difense strong and built damn lot of scud stroms ;) Biggest advantage will be your Jarmen as he alone can destroy an entire base if enemy is a bit careless.
Use your rebel ambush/demolish properly

GLA toxin and China infantry can be difficult to handle.

China Infantry:
Make defense using bunker/gattleing pair or bunker with some mini gunners. Make a helix woth a big bunker and go for their base. also use your tropper vehicle for diffese. Mini gunner drop is damn powerfull. And use you super lotus on a low count super weapon.

Answer (score -2):

With the INF Minigunner + Tank Hunter, you can rush it. Demos should build Demo traps. Lots of them will bring big defenses and SCUDS.